# Identify the outgoing connection (ssh) with the who command

Tags: ssh, who

After a ssh connection, if I run the `who command` on the server : I have this response :

```
olivia@olivia-pc:~$ who
olivia   :0           2014-09-08 11:40 (:0)
olivia   pts/0        2014-09-08 11:43 (:0)
olivia   pts/10       2014-09-08 13:54 (sim.local)
```

So it's easy to identify the incoming connection (third line).

If I run the `who command` on the client : I have this response :

```
who
sim      :0           2014-09-04 16:30 (:0)
sim      pts/10       2014-09-08 13:49 (:0)
sim      pts/0        2014-09-08 13:46 (:0)
```

So I think that the outgoing connection is the second line because it appears after that I connect to the server with `ssh`, but I don't understand why is it still there when I run `who` after that I have closed the connection (and until I leave the terminal).

So my questions are :

1) Is it really the second line that represents the outgoing connection and why?

2) Why is it still visible until I leave the terminal, even if I close the connection?

3) If the outgoing connection is the line two, as I except it to be, is there a reason that server and client use the same pseudo terminal number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Not necessarily.  Either line 2 or 3 is the *terminal* (eg `xterm`) that you are  using to run the `ssh` command.
2. Because it's the terminal, not the `ssh` connection.
3. Complete coincidence. If you consider a Windows user connecting to the server using `PuTTY`, they will not have a local `pts` and neither will they have the `who` command to run.

You can try and run the following to see which `pts` the `ssh` command is running in:

```
ps -AF | grep ssh
```

You should see a `pts` listed against the `ssh` command you are using to connect. This is the `pts` of the `xterm` (or KDE/Gnome terminal etc) that you are using to run `ssh`.

`ssh` itself is connecting to the server using TCP, which you can see using:

```
ss | grep ssh
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! Is there a way to determine which line is the outgoing connection with the server?